# Split text into paragraphs based on criteria using python

Tags: python, text, apache-tika, paragraph

I've converted an [unstructured pdf](https://www.responsibilityreports.com/HostedData/ResponsibilityReports/PDF/NYSE_MCD_2021.pdf) (using tika) into readable text, separated into individual sentences (though these could be merged into one big blob of text if that's easier). See here for a sample of the text:

```
['guided by our core values, weve experienced first-hand how our focused actions both big and small can translate into meaningful experiences for our customers, bringing our purpose to feed and foster community to life each day.',
 'with the strength of our full system, weve worked together to build a more diverse, equitable and inclusive business, source more food responsibly, adopt more sustainable practices, and implement innovative and credible solutions in our ongoing quest to be a good neighbor in the communities where we live, work and serve.',
 'we are proud of the work we do to make a difference and will continue to help uphold this promise in all of the communities in which we operate.',
 'showing up for our communities ray kroc used to say, none of us is as good as all of us a phrase that serves as a constant reminder of mcdonalds impact on the world when we leverage thecollective strength of our system.',
 'we all felt this sentiment more deeply overthe past two years as we continued tonavigate the covid-19 pandemic andit is equally as prevalent now as we face ongoing headwinds.',
 'front of mind is the continuing humanitarian crisis resulting from the war against ukraine.',
 'our hearts and minds remain with the ukrainian people and all impacted, as the ongoing war has brought new elements of uncertainty tocommunities around the world.',
 'in moments like these, our number one priority remains our people.']
```

But now I want to build it back into paragraphs based on a particular set of criteria. Each paragraph should:

- be longer than 2 lines
- consist of 50% alphabetical characters
- contain at least one full stop
- end on a full stop
- consist of a minimum of 20 words, 15 of which should be different

I've tried looping through with ifelse criteria, but I'm getting nowhere.

How should I go about this? Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: That's not separated into sentences, at least not properly.  There is  lots of missing punctuation.  What's the point of separating into paragraphs without any notion of grammar or context?  This is going to be a job for human analysis, I fear.

Comment: Isn't *"contains at least one full stop"* already captured in *"end on a full stop"* ? Or should a paragraph contain *two* full stops? Also what do you mean with *"longer than 2 lines"*? Length wise, or delimited by full stops?

Comment: You're probably going to need regular expressions for this - though it's not going to be an easy pattern to define!